# How to implement mobile menu on desktop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I have:

```
<div class="module left site-title-container">
    <?PHP 
       shapely_get_header_logo(); 
    ?>
</div>
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs"> 
  <i class="fa fa-bars"</i>
```

Which I changed to

```
<div class="module left site-title-container">
    <?php 
        shapely_get_header_logo();
    ?>
</div>
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs"> 
    <a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
        <div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    </a> 
<script>
    function myFunction(x){
        x.classList.toggle('change');
    }
</script>
```

Css

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.change .bar1 {
-webkit-transform: 
rotate(-45deg) 
    translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) 
    translate(-9px, 6px);
}
.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}
.change .bar3 {
-webkit-transform: 
rotate(45deg) 
    translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) 
    translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

This works fine on [mobile](https://4309.co.uk)but not sure how to implement on desktop. I have show mobile menu on desktop like so:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'mobile_menu_on_desktop', true ) ? ' mobile-menu' : ''; ?>" role="banner">
    <div class="nav-container">
```

but still, it's not showing...

So how do I implement the above menu bars animation on desktop? Is it just a case of changing the `a id`?

Something is there on desktop but it seems to be hidden as, when I click where the menu bars should be, the menu responds but no bars are actually visible.

Comment: Did you checked it on a desktop device?

Comment: @Avishka well, on a responsive design checker..